# Dock forgets windows assigned to favorited application

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-dock, favorites

I am having trouble with firefox and the dock. When freshly started, everything works as expected, but after a while (usually overnight with the computer asleep) the dock forgets that any windows are open.

It no longer allows switching to them by clicking on the dock, instead a new windows opens. The existing windows are still functioning, but I cannot switch to them using the dock. Closing/opening Firefox temporarily resolves the problem.

Interestingly enough, when unfavoriting firefox the windows do show up again, but also disappear when setting it as favorite.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and GNOME 42.9

Anyone has some suggestions on how to fix this?